Is it possible to develop an app using Flutter for both Android and WearOS smartwatches, utilizing NFC for communication between the two?
I'm interested in developing an application using Flutter that targets both Android smartphones and WearOS smartwatches. The objective is to establish communication between the smartphone and the smartwatch app utilizing NFC technology. However, I'm uncertain about the NFC functionality on WearOS. Is it restricted solely to payment-related tasks, or is it possible to utilize NFC for general communication purposes between the smartphone and the smartwatch app?
I've tried to find something online about that but all the topics were from 2 years ago; so I didn't find anything useful.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

According to the documentation, it does appear to be possible to write an application to read/write NFC tags on WearOS. The rest of your question is all academic, otherwise. :)
Edit: I am wrong. See the comment below. Thanks for the correction!

Most Wear OS devices don't support reading NFC (source)
